# Facebook Graph API to access Groups

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am seeking some advice, I want to use the Facebook API (V2.7) to simply access the events listed under a private group that I am an admin of. I've read the docs and it seems weird to me that you need to setup an app in order to do this, especially as I am the only person using the app.

If anybody else has any experience could they shed some light here? To iterate I want to make an API call to the Facebook Graph API to simply get a list of all events that the group has listed.

The whole App VS access token isn't too clear to me either (fairly new to Facebook API)

Comment: Yes you need to "setup" an app. Like click Create App button. That's it. You need to use a user access token. Like the documentation say.

Comment: why is is weird? you want to use the graph api, so you need an app. the rest is in the docs.